# Powers inequality proof

Tags: exponentiation

I don't even understand what this proof is asking, let alone how to do it.
here it is:
Show that if $x>1$ is a real number and if $a<b$ are rational numbers, then $0\le x^a \le x^b$.

 any hints or help would be awesome!

Comment: You can use `\le`for $\le$

Comment: This is simply saying: prove that if a,b are both real numbers and a is strictly smaller than b,and if x is strictly larger than 1 then  $0$ is smaller than or equal to $x^a$ is smaller than or equal to $x^b$ So think about what happens when a,b are both integers and think about what happens if a,b are both smaller than one etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1. What does $a<b$ mean in terms of integers?
2. Recall the definition of $x^{p/q}$ where $p,q$ are integers.